# Knockout foreach binding does not work after jQuery UI sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a bunch of rows which update by foreach binding. And I also have a custom knockout binding (based on jQuery UI sortable) which allows to reorder that rows with drag-and-drop.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: serviceTemplates, draggableList: null">
  <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>

ko.bindingHandlers.draggableList = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var panelList = $(element);
    panelList.sortable();
  }
};
```

Row can be deleted. And it works only if I did not move this row. I do not understand why. Does jQuery UI remove and add DOM element while moving it?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JSg/2/)

Comment: You should use the [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) plugin instead of writing your own...

Comment: if you haven't already seen this, this is the classic blog post on using sortable with knockout http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable). All you have to do is to include `knockout-sortable.js` file in your project and replace `foreach` with `sortable`.

```
<tbody data-bind="sortable: serviceTemplates, draggableList: null">
    <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```